# How to send Data from aspx page using Ajax on userclick to C# page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am working with .Net Framework 4.6.1 I have a aspx page that renders data using a Telerik controller. I need to be able to pass properties from the Telerik controller back to the C# page. I have it set up so that when the user clicks on a row column it runs the ajax method with a hardcoded value. I'm unable to send my value using Ajax, I get sent to the error response right away. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm searched everywhere for documentation but none of it works with my framework...
[aspx.cs page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90uK8.png)
[aspx page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUy4b.png)

***ASPX Page***

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="False" AllowFilteringByColumn="False" OnNeedDataSource="GetPharmacyByCorporate">
    <ClientSettings>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" ScrollHeight="650px" UseStaticHeaders="True"></Scrolling>
        <ClientEvents OnRowClick="sendIndex" />
        <%-- On user click (client side) --%>
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
        </Columns>
        <%-- Columns renders every item passed --%>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<script>
    function sendIndex() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/CorpPharmacyList/getIndexed",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { "indexValue": "4" },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log("Post successful");
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("There was an error with the ajax call")
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

***C# Page***

```
public class indexed
    {
        public int indexValue { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void getIndexed(indexed indexe)
    {
        try {
            var myVar = indexe.indexValue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I get back the the console.log("There was an error with the ajax call")

Comment: Right, that's the output you create when any error is encountered.  But that's not the *actual error*.  When you debug, what does `e` contain within that JavaScript function?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the response HTTP code and response body from the server?  Are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?

Comment: I looked in the Network tab and all the responses return a 200 status code... So, would that mean that code in the C# page is what is at fault?

Comment: Check the browser's development console, and use the browser's script debugger to place a breakpoint in that `error` callback function to examine the contents of `e`.  If something is triggering an error, your immediate goal is to find out what that error is.

Comment: Thank you @David I will look into this and will keep you update when I come to a solution.

Comment: This is the error I'm gettng
"Unexpected token '<', "

<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment on the question above...

> This is the error I'm gettng "Unexpected token '<', " <!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"

That means the server isn't returning JSON, it's returning HTML.  But the JavaScript code is explicitly expecting JSON:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Looking at the server-side code, this makes sense.  Because the server-side code doesn't return *anything*:

```
public void getIndexed(indexed indexe)
```

So it would appear that it is defaulting to a page of some kind.

You can tell the JavaScript code to expect HTML instead:

```
dataType: 'html',
```

If you modify the server-side code to return JSON data, just remember to change it back on the client.